# How do I get access token from website automaticaly using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, post, access-token

I am trying to do some web scraping from [here](https://www.wizink.pt/public/credito-pessoal#/) but I am struggling to get the access token automaticaly. Everytime I do the web scraping, I need to manually update the Bearer token. Is there a way to do this automaticaly?

Let me show you how I do it manually:

```
url_WiZink = 'https://www.creditopessoal.wizink.pt/gravitee/gateway/api-chn-loans/v1/loans/quotation'
    
headers_WiZink = {'Accept': 'application/json',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'pt-PT',
'Authorization': 'Bearer de6ea490-381e-417f-ab77-3aad0d7eb63c', 
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Content-Length': '266',
'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
'Host': 'www.creditopessoal.wizink.pt',
'Origin': 'https://www.wizink.pt',
'Referer': 'https://www.wizink.pt/',
'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36',
'X-Channel-Id': 'LOANSIMULATOR',
'X-Client-Id': 'simWzkPt',
'X-Country-Id': 'PRT',
'X-Device-UUID': 'd14e9b629804cbba1ac7c3e78ab39a56'}
        

payload_WiZink = {"productCode":"WZP01","fixedTermLoanId":84,"impositionAmount":{"amount":10000,"currency":"EUR"},"settlementDay":"5","dueOrAdvanceInterestIndicator":"3","nominalInterest":"8.0000000","feeRateId":"05","settlementFrequencyId":"0001","deprecationFrequencyId":"0001"}

response_WiZink = requests.post(url_WiZink, headers=headers_WiZink, json=payload_WiZink, verify=False).json()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that website, you can get an access token by calling their `oauth/token` endpoint:

```py
import requests

access_token = requests.post(
    'https://www.creditopessoal.wizink.pt/gravitee/gateway/api-chn-auth-server/v1/oauth/token',
    headers={'Authorization': 'Basic c2ltV3prUHQ6YmllZTktZmR6dzAzLXBvZWpuY2Q='},
    data={'grant_type': 'client_credentials'},
).json()['access_token']

print(access_token)
```